# Program that shows the sound output in decibels of my speakers

Tags: 20.04, sound, software-recommendation, ubuntu-mate, speakers

Is there a program for Ubuntu 20.04 that shows the sound output in decibels of my speakers? My speakers are connected to a home computer system.

Comment: I'm not sure this is even a Linux question.  What you're asking is an electrical engineering problem: speaker tolerances and voltages vs. output.  The only way to detect proper decibel levels is with a **calibrated sound monitor** and that also requires you have a fairly-accurately calibrated and tuned microphone that is able to *do* the calculation.  However, unless you have a calibrated decibel meter to do this you won't be able to *accurately* determine the levels. (Sound meters use calibrated microphones to accurately detect decibel output, not *apps* on computers).

Comment: Can someone explain why there is so many down-votes to this question? +4 -5.? None of the downvoters provided a helpful comment to the OP so the question could be improved. That's not nice.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is possible. Given the same output signal from the computer, different sound devices will produce different intensities of sound (consider an earphone and a loudspeaker, where the same input signal is used), and the computer would not know that.

To measure the intensity, perhaps you can use some measurement device (which might be read by the computer). But the computer itself cannot determine what intensity of sound (which is measured in decibels) is being produced with the output signal it generates.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am not ready to give up on an answer.

Comment: @fixit7 As a sound engineer, I can tell you accurate Decibel measurement can only come from the output of all the speakers in the sound system. It has nothing to do with the sound output on your computer.

Comment: Computer software can tell the "signal level" that is fed into the sound generating electronics. All beyond that will be unknown for software, until you have an (external) measurement device that can be read by the (same) software.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Answer (score 6):

My laptop can energize my laptop speakers or a entire football stadium sound system.

**The short answer:**

Accurate decibel measurement can only come from measuring the output of each speaker in the sound system with a decibel meter (At a close range). The intensity (dB) of sound changes depending on the distance from the individual or combined speaker sources.

Decibels can only be accurately determined by the output of your sound system and the listeners location, not by your computer output.

**The long answer:**

Setting up a sound system begins with the final output, then work your way back to the source. So we start with your amplifier connected to you speakers. For Optimal performance, Your amplifier should be proceeded by a equalizer so the amplifier can be calibrated to reproduce the exact sound fed through the equalizer. (Every amplifier reacts differently to sound input), thus the necessity of a equalizer.

Next, your amplifier should be calibrated to reproduce the exact sound that is fed into it from the equalizer. This is accomplished by providing "white noise" to the equalizer feeding your amplifier.

Lets pause here and define **"White noise"**.....

**What is White noise?**

White noise refers to noise that is produced by combining of all audible sound frequencies. If you took all of the imaginable tones that a human can hear and mashed them together, you would have white noise.

So using a spectrum analyzer, you adjust your equalizer to reproduce each frequency at the same volume level to your amplifier.

Once this is done **Do not touch the settings!**, Unless future calibration is desired.

Then we move down to the next line of the **Audio source:**

This could be a soundboard or laptop/computer. When the equalizer gets changed at this level, Your main amplifier instantly responds and produces a different dB level.

Back to my **"Short answer" :**

**Decibels can only be accurately determined by the output of your sound system and the listeners location, not by your computer output.**

Comment: @fixit7 I updated my answer to include the "long answer" for your consideration.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly impossible, which can be shown by a simple thought experiment:

1. Assume that such an app exists. It checks the levels you are sending to the loudspeaker, it looks up the efficiency and frequency response of the loudspeaker on Google and uses those values to convert the voltage and current sent to the speaker, and does everything correctly.
2. Now unplug the speaker.
3. Since the levels sent to the (now-unplugged) speaker are still the same as before, the app will still show the same value.

Ergo, such an app cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's theoretically possible to do this.

In order to make it possible though, you'll need to put some work into mapping sound intensity produced by your speakers (and amplifier, if they're passive speakers) versus the output voltage from your PC. No-one else can *ever* do this for your specific setup, only you. And to do this, you'll need a calibrated sound level meter to do the readings.

But if you've got a calibrated sound level meter in the first place, clearly you don't need to do this at all. Just put the sound through your system, and read the level off the meter.

I hope you see the problems here. No app exists, because no-one wants to do this.

Comment: I don't see how it would even be theoretically possible. Simple example: speakers are broken and producing no sound. The software tool would still give you the decibels it thinks it's producing.

Comment: @Graham It does not necessarily have to be an app.I have a sound level app on my phone. I know it is not laboratory grade, but my experiments using it show that it probably comes to within 10% of the actual value. I think positively.

Comment: @fixit7 On your phone, yes. With a microphone that handles fairly well known volume levels. You're not getting the difference between a fairly well-defined microphone, compared to an unknown set of speakers which could be literally anything from earbuds to Metallica's touring rig.

Comment: @terdon True, but you have to start with the assumption that the calibration the app knows about would match the physical hardware. Even assuming that though, the act of calibration is hard enough to be an issue.

Comment: @fixit7 And if you're happy with your phone's SPL meter, working how it does, why not just use that instead of wishing for something which doesn't exist?